# iMessage extension configure long press actionsheet

Tags: ios, ios10, imessage

Is their a way to configure the long press on a message that was sent? For instance if you long press on text you have the ability to copy and tap more. Currently my app only displays more. Is their a way to add copy in the action sheet for custom apps as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the transcript of the conversation is not accessible to us. It's part of the iMessage app. For that reason you won't be able to custom the option menu.